# Get rid of horizontal overflow of html video tag

Tags: html, css, video

I'm using a video as a background for a div on my website. It's not a fixed div. When I use a small resolution I get overflow on the right side, how do I get rid of this? I've been trying with no luck...

It's deployed here: [www.lextoc.com](http://www.lextoc.com/)

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot with the used resolution when the problem occurs? I'm trying to simulate the overflow-problem but without success.

Comment: You can use `max-width:100%;` for video element(`video#banner-video`).

Comment: @SebassvanBoxel http://i.imgur.com/IigFjiR.png

Comment: @alirezasafian The video fills up the current resolution (responsive). I don't want black borders on my video so that's not an option, thanks for suggesting though.

Answer (score 0):

Change `width` to `100%` for `video#banner-video` in your `stylesheet.css` line no 53. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: I don't want black borders on my video. I don't mind it overflowing, I just want to hide the actual overflow.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick, not sure if it's the best solution...

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```